# Can I combine two different groups in correlation analysis?

Tags: regression

Is it acceptable to combine data/observations from eg. cancer patients and healthy individuals during correlations analysis or is it more appropriate to deal with the two groups separately?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you only need to do one analysis. Without knowing any more details about your question or what you're correlating, my intuition is that you should just do everything combined, and then split them for a subgroup analysis and see if you get the same answer. In the picture below (drawn hastily on my phone), $x$ and $y$ are positively correlated across the whole dataset, but you see something completely different if you study the two groups separately. That is an interesting result.

The two strategies I can see from here are 1) do a whole group then subgroup analysis or 2) use a linear mixed effects model that can account for the grouping of data. Just make sure to account for multiple testing, because if you do too many subgroup analyses, you'll end up finding Capricorns don't get heart disease (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4273867/)

[image]